# How can I move my SVN working copy to Codeplex, maintainting file properties, but not history?

Tags: svn, properties, codeplex, file-properties

I am about to open-source one of my projects, and I want to move the current instance of it into CodePlex.

How would I go about copying the current working directory into CodePlex's SVN, maintainting pile properties (like "svn:needs-lock" and "svn:mime-type"), without maintaining history?

I don't want or need the history moved, I will continue to archive the history of the project on my own.  I just don't want to have to manually set "svn:needs-lock" on all of my binary files again.

Comment: I assume you have local repository from where you checked out...now you would like to get this checked out to CodePlex's svn...you simple have to do an svn export of your current state and do an import on the other side..If you like to maintain the history yourself instead in CodePlex.